# Are there known performance issues using jQuery's insertAfter() with select boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have two "pages" (basically two div tags; only one is shown at a time). Depending on what "page" the user is on, the select box will either appear in a jQuery UI dialog on page 1 (as a slider), or on page 2 as a normal select box. My question is, can I use insertAfter() to move the select box from one page/div to another? Or, more specifically, is there any reason I shouldn't? I've shied away from the clone() function because it creates duplicate IDs, and basically making a copy of each select box and trying to sync their values seems like overkill, unless there is a good reason to not use insertAfter().

Here's a mock-up of the code, in case my explanation lacked clarity:

HTML:

```
    <div id="page1">
         <select id="tango">
            <option>Jester</option>
         </select>
    </div>

<div id="page2">
   <div id="dialog">
       <!-- Select Menu would be inserted/moved here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('select#tango').insertAfter('#dialog');
```

Comment: (Assuming I understand your question correctly), why aren't you just including the select in both places, given that you're already show/hiding the divs? Does the select change?

Comment: try `$('#dialog').after($('select#tango'));​`

Comment: @Colleen, no, they're just huge with a ton of options, and I have about 10 of them. Plus, moving one back and forth is easier and uses less code than syncing the values between two of them.

Comment: out of curiosity, what do you mean 'syncing the values' if the values aren't changing? Do you just mean syncing which value is selected? I would think that would be pretty easy-- just $(select-selector).val(otherselector.val()), right? I guess theoretically the bigness could slow page load, but maybe you could cache them or something? Or clone them at the beginning, not on every onclick function call. Seems like moving them around would be potentially more code than just an onclick = hide.

Comment: That's a good point, I may just replicate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `$('select#tango').insertAfter('#dialog');` script would actually result in:

```
<div id="page2">
   <div id="dialog">

   </div>
   <!-- Select Menu would be inserted/moved here -->
</div>
```

I think what you'd really want to have it placed where you wish would be:

```
$('select#tango').appendTo('#dialog');
```

Comment: I'll have to double check tomorrow, but I had it working when I used insertAfter() like that. My question was more "is this a bad idea or are there bad side effects" than "does this work." Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely try it that way tomorrow.

Comment: Not sure why insertAfter seemed to work for my application, but appendTo() is what I'm using now, (actually.clone().appendTo()) so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, can I use insertAfter() to move the select box from
>   one page/div to another? Or, more specifically, is there any reason I
>   shouldn't?

No, there's no reason why you can't or shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it. Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/FA23E/

HTML code

```
<div id="page1">
     <select>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div id="page2">
   <div id="dialog">
       <!-- Select Menu would be inserted/moved here -->
   </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Dance for me !" />
```

Javascript code

```
var clicks = 0,
    $select = $("select"),
    $targets = [ $("#dialog"), $("#page1") ];

$("input").on("click", function() {
    var $target = $targets[ clicks++ % 2 ];

    $select.appendTo( $target  );
});
```